# Unable load a jsp file as a wlecome file in a GAE web application

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine

I am working on a GAE web application that uses a jsp file as a welcome file. But the server shows "Internal Server Error" and "Null Pointer Exception" when i run it locally. I have inclulded the jsp file name in the web.xml as well,still i am getting an error.Please help me to resolve the issue.
Thanks!

> This is my web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Calculator1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.calc1.project.Calculator1Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Calculator1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/calculator1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>newfile.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

> This is my jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Gpa Calculator</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:royalblue">
<p style="font-size:60px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">Online GPA Calculator for Anna  University Affiliated Institutions</p>
<center>
<p style="font-size:50px;text-align:center">Enter Your Grades and Subject Credits</p>
<form method="post" action="calculator1" name="myform" onsubmit="return check()">
<table style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<input type="text" name="name" >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>College:</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input type="text" name="college">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject 1:</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<select name="subject1">
<option value="10">A</option>
<option value="9">B</option>
<option value="8">C</option>
<option value="7">D</option>
<option value="6">E</option>
</select>
</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
Credits:<input type="text" name="credits1" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject 2:</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<select name="subject2">
<option value="10">A</option>
<option value="9">B</option>
<option value="8">C</option>
<option value="7">D</option>
<option value="6">E</option>
</select>
</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
Credits:<input type="text" name="credits2" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject 3:</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<select name="subject3">
<option value="10">A</option>
<option value="9">B</option>
<option value="8">C</option>
<option value="7">D</option>
<option value="6">E</option>
</select>
</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
Credits:<input type="text" name="credits3" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject 4:</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<select name="subject4">
<option value="10">A</option>
<option value="9">B</option>
<option value="8">C</option>
<option value="7">D</option>
<option value="6">E</option>
</select>
</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
Credits:<input type="text" name="credits4" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject 5:</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<select name="subject5">
<option value="10">A</option>
<option value="9">B</option>
<option value="8">C</option>
<option value="7">D</option>
<option value="6">E</option>
</select>
</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
Credits:<input type="text" name="credits5" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject 6:</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<select name="subject6">
<option value="10">A</option>
<option value="9">B</option>
<option value="8">C</option>
<option value="7">D</option>
<option value="6">E</option>
</select>
</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td> 
Credits:<input type="text" name="credits6" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
<td></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="Reset" value="Reset">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check()
{
    var a=document.forms["myform"]["credits1"].value;
    var b=document.forms["myform"]["credits2"].value;
    var c=document.forms["myform"]["credits3"].value;
    var d=document.forms["myform"]["credits4"].value;
    var e=document.forms["myform"]["credits5"].value;
    var f=document.forms["myform"]["credits6"].value;
    var nameCheck = document.forms["myform"]["name"].value;
    var collegeCheck = document.forms["myform"]["college"].value;

    if(a==""||b==""||c==""||d==""||e==""||f==""||nameCheck==""||collegeCheck=="")
    {
    alert("Please fill in the details!!");
    return false;
    }
    else 
        return true;

}
</script>
<p style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold">Your Result:
<%
double gpa = (Double) request.getAttribute("gpa");
out.println(gpa);
%>
</p>
```

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: I just resolved it. The issue was in the scriptlet and i changed it as 
    out.println(request.getAttribute("gpa"));

Answer (score 0):

Please check newfile.jsp file. Issue lies there only for such exceptions. or post the content of jsp file for better understanding.

Comment: I have posted my jsp file now.